# Android activity lifecycle and fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have been working with fragments for a while and what I find frustrating that I cannot get state of activity from fragment. I cannot do something like

`if (getActivity().getState == ActivityState.PAUSED)`

Is there any universal way to handle activity lifecycle changes in fragment without a lot of boilerplate and callback overrides in activity or do I have to manually implement some state manager myself?

**EDIT**
Example:
In activity I need to load data. If data is empty, display one fragment, if not empty - display another. So async call is started, meanwhile activity went to paused state. Commiting fragment causes exception.

```
getAllXCommand.execute(new Callback<Result<List<X>>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Result<List<X>> data) {
            Logger.d(String.format("Received addresses: %d", data.getData().size()));
            //How to get state of activity here?
            if (data.getData().isEmpty()) {
                setEmptyFragment();
            } else {
                setXFragment(data.getData());
            }
            addRemovePresenter.enableAddAction();
        }
    });
```

Comment: May I know why you need to know the status of Activity to which Fragment is attached?

Comment: can you post the exception please?

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean variable to your activity that is changed in `onPause` and `onResume` and check it.

Comment: Edited. If I want to attach fragment after some async call, I call commit, but how do I check if activity is resumed. In your scenario, fragment should have already benn attached.

Comment: Exactly! I am talking about this boiler-plate stuff. I want to avoid it, maybe there is some better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did what I didn't want to do. I created base activity for all activities and enumeration for activity states I am interested in.

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity{

private ActivityState activityState;

public ActivityState getActivityState() {
    return activityState;
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    activityState = ActivityState.RESUMED;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    activityState = ActivityState.PAUSED;
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    activityState = ActivityState.STOPPED;
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    activityState = ActivityState.DESTR0YED;
}
}

public enum ActivityState {
RESUMED(true), PAUSED, STOPPED, DESTR0YED;
boolean canAddFragment;

ActivityState(boolean canAddFragment) {
    this.canAddFragment = canAddFragment;
}

ActivityState() {
    this(false);
}

public boolean canAddFragment() {
    return canAddFragment;
}
}
```